# iOS Multipeer Connectivity didReceiveInvitationFromPeer did not

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question has been asked many times, but after reading each of them more than a few times, I still can't get my `Multipeer Connectivity` to work. I am sending but not receiving the invitation. Here is the code:

```
@implementation MPCManager

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    _myPeerID = nil;
    _session = nil;
    _browser = nil;
    _advertiser = nil;
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)automaticBrowseAndAdvertiseWithName:(NSString *)displayName {
  _myPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:displayName];
  _session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_myPeerID];
  _session.delegate = self;

  _advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:_myPeerID
                                                  discoveryInfo:nil
                                                    serviceType:@"trm-s"];
  _advertiser.delegate = self;
  [_advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];

  _browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:_myPeerID
                                              serviceType:@"trm-s"];
  _browser.delegate = self;
  [_browser startBrowsingForPeers];
}

- (void)session:(MCSession *)session
    didReceiveCertificate:(NSArray *)certificate
                 fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
       certificateHandler:(void (^)(BOOL accept))certificateHandler {
  certificateHandler(YES);
}

- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser
    didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
                     withContext:(NSData *)context
               invitationHandler:(void (^)(BOOL,
                                           MCSession *))invitationHandler {
  NSLog(@"This is NOT getting called");
}

- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser
    didNotStartBrowsingForPeers:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser
            foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
    withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  NSLog(@"This IS getting called");
}

- (void)invitePeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
  NSLog(@"This IS getting called");
  [_browser invitePeer:peerID toSession:_session withContext:nil timeout:30];
}
```

I am running it on two simulators, and it was working for some time, but stopped suddenly. Any ideas on how or where to look for the problem?

Comment: Which OS and version are you working with here? One thing I have found is that you should be serializing your MCPeerID objects and reusing them if the device name hasn't changed. Otherwise the browsing process can get polluted with duplicates. Does this work if you run it on real hardware?

Comment: I _Product/Clean_-ed my project and reset simulator with _iOS Simulator/Reset Content and Settings..._ and it's working again, so I guess the problem was the one you mentioned. Would you convert it to answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I added my answer. The session I linked has code in it for handling the serializing of the MCPeerID objects. That one tip alone has made a huge difference in my multipeer code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are serializing and reusing your MCPeerID objects whenever possible. Each time you call `- (instancetype)initWithDisplayName:(NSString *)myDisplayName` it returns a unique instance.

What often happens in a dev environment is that you end up with a flood of advertisers and browsers and a ton of ghost duplicates in the Bonjour advertising space. This can cause everything to just go wonky.

If you are using simulators then resetting them may help. On hardware you can restart or toggle airplane mode.

Take a look at [this year's WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) on Multipeer named "Cross Platform Nearby Networking". It has some good best practices to follow that will help immensely.

Comment: when you say `serialize`, I think store as binary, but does this imperatively mean set a class variable pointing to the PeerID object? I'm not sure how to explicitly serialize something other than make it data owned by a particular class and wanted to make sure that was all you meant for people to do in your advice.

Comment: Yes, serialize and store it to keep the object from run to run of your app. Check out that WWDC session from 22:30 onwards.